# Sharepoint Crawler is denied access to sites

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2007, web-crawler

We create all our site collections programatically with a custom site def/template. Everything works as expected, except for the crawler. It's apparently denied access to the sites. The crawl logs says:

> http://server.localnetwork.lan/somesites/siteName
>   The object was not found. (The item
>   was deleted because it was either not
>   found or the crawler was denied access
>   to it.)

And in the log files I'm getting this:

> 08/11/2009 14:20:34.01    OWSTIMER.EXE
>   (0x0674)
>     0x1560  Search Server Common
>     MS Search Administration
>     7hmh    High        exception in
>   SearchUpgradeProvisioner Keyword
>   Config
>   System.InvalidOperationException:
>   jobServerSearchServiceInstance is null
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchUpgradeProvisioner..ctor(SearchServiceInstance
>   searchServiceInstance)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.OSSPrimaryGathererProject.ProvisionContentSources()

If I create a site collection manually the crawler is able to access it. The same users/accounts have the same access on both sites, so that shouldn't be the issue.

The code we use to actually create the site collection looks a little like this:

```
SPWebApplication app = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri("WebApplicationUrl"));
app.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = false;
app.Sites.Add("url", "title", "description", "language code", "SiteTemplateName", "Owner.Username", "Owner.Fullname", "Owner.Email");
app.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = true;
```

The code has been slightly altered to protect the innocent... ;)

Any idea what we're doing wrong?

(Please note, I'm not sure if this is a programming error or a config/setup error, so I'm cross-posting with [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/52695/sharepoint-crawler-is-denied-access-to-sites))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you receive this error whilst the crawler account (the default content access account) has read permission to all your sites then you most likely need to disable the loopback check.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

http://koenvosters.wordpress.com/2009/06/15/access-denied-when-using-hostname-search-and-site-on-moss-2007/

Comment: This was the solution. Thanx a bunch!